# Keep track of active call status - Twilio

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I was wondering if it was possible to keep track of the status of an active call using twilio. I am attempting to do so using the following code:

```
Map<String, String> callParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
callParams.put("To", "***********"); 
callParams.put("From", "***********");
callParams.put("Url", "https://**************/");
callParams.put("Method", "GET");
Call call = null;
try {
    call = callFactory.create(callParams);
    System.out.println("Call was " + call.getDuration() + " long.");
    System.out.println("Status " + call.getStatus());            
} catch (TwilioRestException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

The two print statements after the call are an attempt at acquiring the call status (answered, completed etc) but they currently produce null and queued respectively.

Is it at all possible to keep track of the call status somehow, or even get the status duration at the end of the call instead of at the beginning of the call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. The reason why you're getting null during the call is because we will only be able to report call duration when the call has been completed. As you said, you're looking at a call that is still queued, since you has just initiated the request.

We offer [call status callback](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132267-Tracking-the-call-status-of-an-outbound-call) though, which seems to be exactly what you want.

When you start a new call, there are a few [optional parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) you can pass. One of the is called `StatusCallback`, and is a URL that Twilio will send asynchronous webhook requests to on every call event specified in the StatusCallbackEvent.

When Twilio makes this request to the URL you provided, it will pass the [following variables](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#request-parameters). You can then use this variables to get all the information about your call. One of such variables is called `CallDuration`, which is the duration in seconds of the just-completed call.

You can also read more about Status Callback Events in [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/05/introducing-call-progress-events-flexibly-track-and-control-your-outbound-calls.html).

Hope this helps you